# How To Show The Current Time in TextView in Widget

Tags: android, time, textview, widget, updatable-views

I want to show the current time in updatable textView 
I can't find the true way to make it 
I want it to be updated every minute 
Please anyone can help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat oSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String MyString= oSimpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime()); 
EditText oEditText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyEdit);
oEditText.setText(MyString);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You should use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

use the digital clock tag Digital Clock built in android studio 2.1.
**Here it is built in tag to show time**
< Digital Clock > ***don't use space b/w digital and clock,*** it was having problem while posting the answer.